# Using Today() function in SSRS Background Color Expression

Tags: reporting-services

I am trying to create a few SSRS Expressions that will highlight rows when the following cases are met: When the date field = today...When the date field >= today through +120 days...When the date field = Yesterday and all days before that...

This is coming from a Crystal Report with the following code:

```
if  {usp_ND044R01;1.review_Date} in  AllDatesToYesterday
then crYellow
else
if  {usp_ND044R01;1.review_Date} in  CurrentDate to CurrentDate+ 120
then crYellow
else
crWhite
```

This is where I am at:

```
=IIF(Fields!review_Date.Value = Today(), "Yellow", "No Color")
=IIF(Fields!review_Date.Value <= dateadd("d",120,today()), "Yellow", "No Color")
=IIF(Fields!review_Date.Value <= dateadd("d",-1,today()), "Yellow", "No Color")
```

I always get an error (red squiggly line under the parenthesis  right after today. E.G. today**()**

Any suggestion would be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to group the IIF statements together if they're referencing the same row. So you could set the fill properties of the row to something like this:

```
    =IIF(Fields!ProductDate.Value = Today(), "Yellow", 
     IIF(Fields!ProductDate.Value < Today(), "Green",
     IIF(Fields!ProductDate.Value <= dateadd("d",120,Today()), "Blue", "White")))
```

First this will check if the field equals today. If it does, the row will be yellow. Otherwise it checks to see if the field value is less than today's date. In that case, it will be green. If not, it will check to see if the value is less than today's date plus 120 days. If it is, the row will be blue. If all of these statements are false, the row's background will be white.

Comment: This is still giving me an error on the first line after today there is a red squiggly line under the parenthesis.  SSRS doesn't like to share whether it's syntax or what.

Comment: When you try to preview the report, what error does it give you?

Comment: An error occoruded during local report processing.  The definiton of the report '(Report Name)' is invalid.  The backgroundColor expression for the tablix 'table1' refers to the field 'review_date'.  Report item expressions can only refer to fields within the current dataset scope or, if inside an aggregate, the specified dataset scope.  Letters in the names of fields must use the correct case. (The field is in the current dataset).

Comment: Also, the field is in the correct case, and the report runs fine without the expression.  The highlighted rows just aern't there obviously.  I am using the same field in the report and expression, which leads me to believe that its not the field, its the expression.

Comment: What does your dataset look like?

Comment: Its a simple dataset with 9 fields.  Datatypes may vary.  I'm not sure what you meant by the question.

Comment: Could you edit your question to include some sample data from when the report runs without the expression?

Comment: Samples have been included.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it working using the following expression:
    =IIF(Fields!review_Date.Value < DateAdd("d",120,Today) or Fields!review_Date.Value <= Today, "Yellow", "White")